# Proper place for human-readable representation of entity-based key

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, entity, static-methods

First some background.  We recently converted from a Zend_Db_Table-based solution to entity-based solution (Doctrine).  As our application grew, the table classes grew uglier and uglier.  Some of the tables used ENUM columns to store string-based keys, which were converted into human-readable strings with static methods.  Something like this:

```
public static function getProductType($productKey)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($productKey, self::$productTypes)) {
        return null;
    }
    return self::$productTypes[$productKey];
}

public static function getProductTypes()
{
    return self::$productTypes;
}
```

In moving to the entity-based system, I tried to avoid static methods where possible.  I moved the key to value translations into a view helper and called it a day.  In the end, I found that it was not sufficient, as we needed to return them in JSON objects, which occurred outside of the presentation layer (i.e. no direct access to view helpers).

Does anyone have any theories on the proper place for these types of methods?  Should I create separate objects for doing the translation from key to human-readable value, implement static methods on the entity object, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Well my theory is that this should be done in the model itself. But sometimes when dealing with a complex model, I like to create a separate class that handles any special "presentation" of that model. It takes the model as an argument and encapsulates the presentation logic.

So using your example, perhaps something like this:

```
class Model_Product
{
    public static function getAllTypes()
    {
        return array(/* key-value pairs */);
    }

    //returns non human readable value
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->_type;
    }
}

class Model_Product_Presenter
{
    protected $_model;

    public function __construct(Model_Product $model)
    {
        $this->_model = $model; 
    }

    //returns human readable value
    public function getType()
    {
        $types = $this->_model->getAllTypes();

        if (!array_key_exists($this->_model->type, $types)) {
            return null;
        }
        return $types[$this->_model->type];
    }

    public function getDateCreated($format = "Y-m-d")
    {
        return date($format,$this->_model->timestamp);
    }
}
```

You can go further and create a base presenter class to define any common tasks, i.e. converting timestamps to dates, formatting numbers, etc.

**Update:**
For anonymous access to a list of product types, I don't see any harm in making it the responsibility of the product model via a static method. Not all static methods are evil. In my opinion, the use of static methods for this purpose is fine, because it declares a global constant.

In a more complex scenario, I would delegate this responsibility to a separate class like Model_ProductType. Here is an example of such a complex model in production:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/master/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type.php

Comment: What about a situation where all of the key => value data must be used for say...a dropdown element?  If I'm dealing with entities only, the choice is simple, but outside of that construct, when I'm not using any entities but I need data related to an theoretical entity, I'm still at square one.

Comment: In my opinion, maintaining a list of product types and the associated human readable descriptions should be the responsibility of a model. In your example, depending on the complexity, it could be part of the Product model or perhaps a ProductType model. If there is a requirement for anonymous access to the maintained list, then so be it. I'll update my answer with a product model example from the Magento source code. Their Product/Type requirements seems quite complex and obviously warranted a class of its own.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Christian.  It's been helpful to read your opinion on these matters.  As far as Magento is concerned, I think Magento is a great application, but its structure is a bit different from our own.  They tend to use the singleton pattern and static methods to drive their application, whereas we do not.  That's not to say that we can't find a few good ideas.  I'll look further into what you've suggested here and see if it is a fit.  Thanks again!